# Make extended shape class listen to stagemousedown event

Tags: javascript, class, event-handling, dom-events, easeljs

I have created player class in EaselJS by extending shape like so:

```
var Player = createjs.extend(function Player (color, x, y) {
    this.Shape_constructor();
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.graphics.beginFill(color).drawCircle(0, 0, 10);
}, createjs.Shape).constructor;
createjs.promote(Player, 'Shape');
```

I would like my player to listen to stagemousedown event, but I don't know how to access it, since it can only be applied to instance of `Stage` class.

Is there a way to propagate that event to all objects in the stage? I can't find any useful info in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any child of the stage can access the stage using the `getStage()` method. This will return null in the constructor (since the child is not on stage until `addChild` is used.

I would recommend making a stage variable accessible to your children (global is the easy way), and then just listen there.

```
// In the global scope
var stage = new createjs.Stage("canvasId");
// Or put it in the global scope
window.myStage = stage;
```

Then it is accessible for any children.

```
stage.on("stagemousedown", handleStageClick);
```

Remember to clean up these listeners when you are done, otherwise they will just stack up. The `on` method creates a method binding behind the scenes, so you will have to store it off to remove it later.

```
this.listener = stage.on("stagemousedown", handleClick);
// On clean-up
this.off(this.listener);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, this helps, although I hoped I can avoid tying my player to a specific stage instance, this seems a bit dirty... :(

Comment: Also, I hoped I can do something like this in player constructor : `this.on('stagemousedown', doSomething);` but yes... than I don't know which stage I'm referring to.

Comment: Ok, so I found out there's actually event called 'added' that gets fired when I add sprite to a stage, and I guess I can than call `getStage()` on `this` to decouple my player from speciffic stage instance, although it is ugly :D

Comment: The added event is handy, but it fires when the child is added to any parent. This means you will get the event, even if the child is actually in a display list that is on the stage. Some people have asked for an `addedToStage` event, similar to Flash, but it is fairly costly to calculate, which is why it is not part of EaselJS. If the added event works for your case, that is great.